# How to get Salesforce refresh token if my redirect url is with https protocol

Tags: salesforce, refresh-token

As per Salesforce documentation,

**The refresh token is only returned if the redirect URI is https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success or used with a custom protocol that is not HTTPS.**

Is there any way to get refresh_token on my url  with **https** protocol

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have work around and I found Solution. 
If you are integrating salesforce with website then you have to use web server flow instead of user-agent flow.

Reference : [Web-server Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm)